# Delay in Authentication using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication

I use `React` for frontend and `Node.js` in backend and `Postgre` for database.

I have create my own API for authenticating user and using `useState` and `useContext` hook to store the login status of the user.

I also setup a Redirect function after successful login but the `useState` is taking a while to update the login status of user and because of that the page is not being redirect.

I tried using `async` and `await` while fetching the data from the server but still there is delay in authenticating the user.

I also tried to follow some blogs like [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow)

This context state handle the login functionality and update the login status within the component.

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "./GlobalState";

export const LoginAuth = createContext();

export const ProvideAuth = ({ children }) => {
  const auth = useProvideAuth();
  return <LoginAuth.Provider value={auth}>{children}</LoginAuth.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(LoginAuth);
};

const useProvideAuth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { setIsLogin } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const login = async (userDetails) => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/login/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(userDetails),
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));

    const data = await response.json();

    if (data?.error) {
      setUser(false);
    } else {
      setUser(data);
      setIsLogin(true);
    }
  };

  return { user, login };
};
```

This state used to update the login state throughout the app

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const GlobalContext = createContext();

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ isLogin, setIsLogin }}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Private Route Code

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router";
import { GlobalContext } from "../State/GlobalState";

const PrivateRouteLogin = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { isLogin } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return isLogin ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          ></Redirect>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRouteLogin;
```

Comment: It can be much better if you share a sample of your code.

Comment: @Saba I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an another value for your loginStatus

```
false = not logged in
true = logged in
pending = for collect all data
```

in this situation you can have a backdrop(loading) that show over your website till detect loginStatus